# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ienumerable

I'm trying to write function to get return all integers from object list and I keep getting: 'Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'.'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<object>() { 1, 2, "a", "b" };
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntegersFromList(list));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> ints = (IEnumerable<int>) listOfItems.Where(x => x is int);
        return ints.ToList();
    }
```

I tried casting it, not casting it, adding ToList() everywhere and I always get the Invalid Cast Exception.

The output should be: {1, 2}

Comment: `ints = listOfItems.OfType<int>();` To be honest, `GetIntegersFromList` is unnecessary because it is simply replicating the behaviour of `Enumerable.OfType`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I returned that and now as the output I get 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1[System.Int32]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq's `Where()` returns a `WhereListIterator<T>`, with `T` being the `T` of the source `IEnumerable<T>`, in your case still `object`.

Either `Cast<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = (IEnumerable<int>)listOfItems.Where(x => x is int).Cast<int>();
```

Or, shorter, use [`OfType<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1):

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = listOfItems.OfType<int>();
```

Comment: I get  'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' as output

Comment: Yes, that's because you write the type name to the console. You need to print the collection's contents, for example `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetIntegersFromList(list))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to write the integers to the console, you will need to convert the `IEnumerable` to a `string`:

```
var list = new List<object>() { 1, 2, "a", "b" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.OfType<int>()));

// Output: 1, 2
```

Or iterate over the `IEnumerable`:

```
var list = new List<object>() { 1, 2, "a", "b" };
foreach (int i in list.OfType<int>()) Console.WriteLine(i);

// Output:
// 1
// 2
```

---

If you must implement `GetIntegersFromList` then you can just create a simple pass through:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
    => listOfItems.OfType<int>();
```

Or if you cannot use LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
{
    foreach (var item in listOfItems)
    {
        if (item is int i) yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to write out the function         public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)

Comment: @Dragana why? That's what `OfType` does.

Comment: Probably homework where they have to provide the implementation of that method. Most likely in that case, Linq isn't allowed either.

Comment: The task goes like this: 'Create a function that takes a list of non-negative integers and strings and returns a new list with the strings filtered out.' and I'm given the blank funciton where I'm suppoused to write the code

Comment: I assume that linq is allowed because it was kinda required in past tasks