# Implementing List<T>, why wont it cast back to MyList after LINQ ? (Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1)

Tags: c#, list, linq

Probably something silly that I'm missing, but so far searching has come up with nothing.
I have implemented `List<T>` on my class, and when using a `MyList.Where()` function it wont cast back to a `MyList` object ?

```
public class VideoList : List<Video>
{
    public VideoList GetVideos(bool onlyShorts)
        => (VideoList)this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts)).ToList();
}
```

Throws error:

> Unable to cast object of type `WhereListIterator1[Video]` to type `VideoList`.

Tried some different types of casting as was suggested online, but thus far i haven't got passed this error.
Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369105/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-wherelistiterator1system-object-to-type-syst), but same problem.
Probably some semantics  ?
Is there a way to resolve this error without foreach recreating the list after the linq statement ?

Comment: Well that's just what `ToList()` returns. You didn't implement a `ToList` that returns a `VideoList`, so why should it do that? You can implement a `ToVideoList` extension method on `IEnumerable<Video>`, but you have to recreate a `VideoList` *somewhere*.

Comment: I think better do not create new class, but extension method `public static IEnumerable<Video> GetVideos(this IEnumerable<Video> videos, bool onlyShorts) => onlyShorts ? videos.Where(x => x.IsShort) : videos;`

Comment: Why would you be able to cast an object as a type that it isn't?

Comment: I understand almost nothing from comments above.

Comment: I highly recommend to check out the [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt) before going forward with `VideoList : List<Video>`. [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) maybe a relevant read also. As for your question and technical reasons - @Sweeper's comment and @rotabor's answer explain why.

Comment: @rotabor those seems to be pretty clear. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @GuruStron super interesting, thanks for the references !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts)).ToList()
```

produces "List<Video>" which can't be **upcasted** to type VideoList.

If you still want GetVideos returns VideoList, you need to have and use the appropriate constructor (as a possible solution):

```
public VideoList(List<Video> videolist) { ... }

public VideoList GetVideos(bool onlyShorts)
    => new VideoList(this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts)).ToList());
```

Comment: Please remove the `ToList` to improve the performance. This will avoid a complete iteration of the result.

Comment: Additionally, to make your code work, `VideoList` must provide the corresponding constructor to pass the `IEnumerable` to the base type's constructor: `public VideoList(IEnumerable<Video> videolist) : base(videolist)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I was able to apply and run the suggested changes successfully.

Answer (score 4):

As the extension method's name `Enumerable.ToList` implies, the return type is a `List<T>`. Having it return an e.g. `ObservableCollection` would be semantically wrong as this is not a `List<T>` (To***List***). Such a method would rather be named `ConvertTo` (from a member naming perspective).

The signature of `Enumerable.ToList` looks as follows:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.List<TSource> ToList<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

By looking at the signature you may understand that the method cannot know the actual collection type it is working on as the original source collection, which is a `VideoList` in your case, is downcasted to `IEnmumerable<T>`. In other words, `Enumerable.ToList` does not know that the source collection is of type `VideoList`.
In addition, in order to return an e.g. `VideoList` the extension method `ToList` would have to invoke the constructor of `VideoList` in order to create a new instance. For simplicity and for performance reasons, the `Enumerable.ToList` avoids this.

To solve your problem, you can make use of deferred execution and the fact that all collections accept an `IEnumerable` as constructor parameter:

```cs
public class VideoList : List<Video>
{
  public VideoList(IEnumerable<Video> videos) : base(videos)
  {
  }

  public VideoList GetVideos(bool onlyShorts)
  {  
    // At this point the query is not executed. It's deffered.
    IEnumerable<Video> videos = this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts));

    // Realize the query (iterate the VideoList only once --> deferred execution)
    return new VideoList(videos);
  }
}
```

The key point is that LINQ's key feature is that it produces deferred queries, called "deferred execution".
This means that `myList.Where()` does not immediately execute. For example, this behavior is achieved by using `yield return`.

Therefore, most of the `Enumerable` extension methods return an `IEnumerable<T>` that is only enumerated once the `IEnuemrable<T>.GetEnumerator` is called and the returned `IEnumerator<T>` is used. This is called realization: the actual query is executed and the result values are generated.
For example, one way to realize the query is thr iteration of the `IEnumerable` result using a `foreach`.
`Enumerable` also defines extension methods that lead to immediate realization. Those methods are for example, `ToList`, `Sum` or `OrderBy`. These types of methods are not able to return an example without having to iterate the complete source collection.
For this reason (performance) we should always make use of deferred execution and avoid `ToList` and its likes. Better think twice, as `ToList` can easily lead to having the source collection iterated twice or more (which can have a serious performance impact if the collection is big enough:

```cs
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var filteredNumbers = numbers
  .Where(number > 3)
  .ToList(); // First complete iteration

// Second complete iteration
foreach (int number in filteredNumber)
{
}
```

For that reason, we always use deferred execution when possible:

```cs
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// At this point, filteredNumbersQuery still contains all the original values
IEnumerable<int> filteredNumbersQuery = numbers.Where(number => number > 3);

// For example, modifying the source collection before the enumeration of the result collection will also modify the realized result
numbers.Add(6);

// Iterating the result using ToList.
// Realizes: 4, 5, 6! The 6 is added because the source collection 
// was modified before the result has been realized. 
// This resulting behavior is important to know as it can lead to "unexpected" 
// side effects if you pass around the returned query result (the `IEnumerable<T>`) 
// while the source collection is modified. 
// We can also make use of this feature, now that we know that 
// the `IEnumerable<T>` will be kept in sync with the source collection.
List<int> filteredNumbers = filteredNumbersQuery.ToList(); // Realizes: 4, 5, 6!

// Because LINQ also uses "lazy evaluation" 
// the following chained enumeration results in a single iteration (and not two).
// In other words, each value passes directly the chain of queries
// (instead of each query being applied to the complete collection):
IEnumerable<string> filteredTextNumbersQuery = numbers
  .Where(number => number > 3) // First query
  .Select(number => number.ToString()); // Second query

// Because of lazy evaluation 
// the chained query results in a single iteration
// once we realize the deferred query e.g. by calling ToList.
List<string> filteredTextNumbers = numbers.ToList(); // Single iteration realizes: "4", "5", "6"
```

Comment: So long lecture. Make your code simple: "{ IEnumerable<Video> videos = this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts)); return new VideoList(videos); }" --> "=> return new VideoList(this.Where(x => x.IsShort.Equals(onlyShorts)));"

Comment: Your "improvements" are not relevant. I was choosing the creating of the local to highlight some behavior. Introducing the local improves the readability which was more important to me than producing the most compact code. The answer to the question is at the very beginning of my post. The rest is just an explanation. You don't have to read the lecture to get the solution. It's optional.